# get date field value from backend to front end

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am making a custom post type plugin so it will be easy to put in any site. I got a reference from [here](http://www.noeltock.com/web-design/wordpress/custom-post-types-events-pt1/)

And made as far it guides me to do but I got stuck in one place. I have used a jquery Calender to display post which is posted on that day. It will show the post as with its start date.

So I tried `get_post_meta( get_the_ID() );` but it didn't help. How can I parse the meta value of dashboard to front-end.
If admin fetch the start date in dashboard is there anyway to retrieve that value to give in the jquery calendar so that it will display the post date correctly as of admin feeds

Comment: you can use get_post_custom($post->ID) or get_post_custom(get_the_ID())

Comment: both returns null value

Comment: try checking the key name of that meta field and call that by get_post_meta( int $post_id, string $key = '', bool $single = false )

Comment: It is solved by using `get_post_meta($post->ID);`